Hold out to the bitter end
The answer to this puzzle is a description of the puzzle.
|| 1. Staff without preamble have yen to make candy (5) ||
| 2. Bardic women have the Trojan and wizard gaining two aces, losing one  (6,3,6) |
| 3. Engineering graduate, we hear, will get Outstanding award (4) |
| 4. Carol made no Mexican article (4) |
| 5. Halo, mostly, or a light in the sky (6) |
| 6. Yeast starter polishes off four vines  (3) |
| 7. Halloween icon has truck in London, allegedly (6) |
| 8. Mark rental red (7) |
| 9. Grandma, oddly coy, is a pussycat (5) |
| 10. This girl is a Frenchwoman? (8) |
| 11. Slimy customer secreted disgusting reaction inside holy book (4) |
| 12. Novel featuring Dorothy's aunt and mother (4) |
| 13. Crown Spanish relative before God (5) |
| 14. Frozen asset from inventor with lost original investment, broken heart (4) |
| 15. 2022 death caused by rotten hazel bite  (9) |
| 16. Sole company in disordered, half-constructed keep  (4) |
| 17. Wood recedes partway on earthy edge (5) |
| 18. Reportedly, I owe Roman king's companion (2) |
| 19. Appear, on grand introductions, perfect (5) |
| 20. The Underworld holds evil lords, leaders (3) |
| 21. 1991 movie with outlandish female, f*** removed in editing (6, 3, 6) |
| 22. Basho writes of snow/occasionally busy/silk reorganized (4) |
| 23. Kalifa unapologetically owns a zoo (5) |
| 24. A shade of green, Lena's husband gets internal saline drip (5) |
| 25. United masses against—primarily--cryptid (3) |
| 26. Thru puzzlement is found compassion (4) |
| 27. Weaver weaves, is younger (9) |
| 28. Dangerous group for myself and sibling (4) |
| 29. Number of vacation activity beginners expand uncontrollably (4) |
| 30. Genetic engineering organization comes to Iowa State (7) |
| 31. Gold held by heartless leader, bronze medal taken finally: Olympic reward (6) |
| 32. Daredevil feature is excitedly related with king, not duke (7) |
| 33. Friend located in all you (4) |
| 34. Bounce by cop (5) |
| 35. Desirable view from upset canoe (5) |
| 36. Nymph will throw up? (6) |
| 37. Floor installer spoke for Whig president (5) |
| 38. Spice ingredient of gin Geraldine (6) |
| 39. Arthurian figure helped, i.e., sheltered seeds (7) |
| 40. 15 gets appetizing starter after Reginald involved (6) |
| 41. Laughing in text: I love you, beloved flower (4) |
|| 42. Bottomless lesbian with fury is a rare gem (8) ||
Commentary:

I realize without a grid solving things may be difficult, but then again I'm not very clever, so hopefully it's not too impossible.


Clues and solutions:

 1. TAFFY | (-s)TAFF + Y | Staff without preamble have yen to make candy (5)
 2. HELENA AND HERMIA | HELEN AND HERMIONE plus two As, minus ONE | Bardic women have the Trojan and wizard gaining two aces, losing one (6,3,6)
 3. EMMY | homophone of M.E. | Engineering graduate, we hear, will get Outstanding award (4) (4)
 4. NOEL | NO + EL | Carol made no Mexican article (4)
 5. AURORA | AUR(-a) + OR A | Halo, mostly, or a light in the sky (6)
 6. IVY | Y(-east) after IV | Yeast starter polishes off four vines (3)
 7. LAURIE | homophone of LORRY | Halloween icon has truck in London, allegedly (6)
 8. SCARLET | SCAR + LET | Mark rental red (7)
 9. NANCY | NAN C(-o)Y | Grandma, oddly coy, is a pussycat (5)
 10. ISABELLE | IS A BELLE | This girl is a Frenchwoman? (8)
 11. NEWT | EW in NT | Slimy customer secreted disgusting reaction inside holy book (4)
 12. EMMA | EM + MA | Novel featuring Dorothy's aunt and mother (4)
 13. TIARA | TIA + RA | Crown Spanish relative before God (5)
 14. ELSA | (-t)ESLA with "broken heart" | Frozen asset from inventor with lost original investment, broken heart (4)
 15. ELIZABETH | (HAZEL BITE)* | 2023 death caused by rotten hazel bite (9)
 16. NIKE | IN* + KE(-ep) | Sole company in disordered, half-constructed keep (4)
 17. EBONY | EB(-bs) on (-earth)Y | Wood recedes partway on earthy edge (5)
 18. IO | homophone | Reportedly, I owe Roman king's companion (2)
 19. GRACE | GR(-and) + ACE | Appear, on grand introductions, perfect (5)
 20. HEL | H(-olds) E(-vil) L(-ords) | The Underworld holds evil lords, leaders (3)
 21. THELMA AND LOUISE | (OUTLANDISH (-f)EMALE)* |  1991 movie with outlandish female, f*** removed in editing (6, 3, 6)
 22. YUKI | (bUsYsIlK)* | Basho writes of snow/occasionally busy/silk reorganized (4)
 23. FAUNA | substring | Kali[fa una]pologetically owns a zoo (5)
 24. OLIVE | OLE gets IV inside | A shade of green, Lena's husband gets internal saline drip (5)
 25. UMA | U_ M_ A_ | United masses against—primarily--cryptid (3)
 26. RUTH | THRU* | Thru puzzlement is found compassion (4)
 27. SIGOURNEY | (IS YOUNGER)* | Weaver weaves, is younger (9)
 28. ISIS | I + SIS | Dangerous group for myself and sibling (4)
 29. NOVA | N_ O_ V_ A_ | Number of vacation activity beginners expand uncontrollably (4)
 30. GEORGIA | G E ORG + IA | Genetic engineering organization comes to Iowa State (7)
 31. LAUREL | AU in L(-eade)R + _E _L | Gold held by heartless leader, bronze medal taken finally: Olympic reward (6)
 32. ELEKTRA | (RELATE(d->K))* | Daredevil feature is excitedly related with king, not duke (7)
 33. ALLY | substring | Friend located in [all y]ou (4)
 34. BOBBY | BOB BY | Bounce by cop (5)
 35. OCEAN | CANOE* | Desirable view from upset canoe (5)
 36. UNDINE | ddef | Nymph  throw up? (5)
 37. TYLER | homophone of TILER | Floor installer spoke for Whig president (5)
 38. GINGER | substring | Spice ingredient of gin Geraldine (6)
 39. IGRAINE | IE sheltering GRAIN | Arthurian figure helped, i.e., sheltered seeds (7)
 40. REGINA | A_ after REG IN | 15 gets appetizing starter after Reginald involved (6)
 41. LILY | L + ILY | Laughing in text: I love you, beloved flower (4)
 42. SAPPHIRE | SAPPH(-o) + IRE | Bottomless lesbian with fury is a rare gem (8)

Title of, and description of, puzzle:

 Initial letters of answers spell out THE NAILS NINETEEN EIGHTY-FOUR SINGLE ABOUT GIRLS, indicating 88 Lines about 44 Women, which is in fact what we have here. (I am ashamed to confess that I didn't notice all the answers were women's names until after figuring this out.)

I'm not quite sure

 what "helped" is doing in the clue for 39.

Credit where due: oAlt figured out 17 (for which I was confident of the answer but baffled by the wordplay).

Deleted my answer, since yours has a strict superset of my answers - didn't realize we were both working on it in parallel! The "things [you] don't understand" are all my suspicions as well, though I haven't been able to confirm them.

There was another one about 24h ago that three of us all got approximately to the end of at approximately the same time. I'd decry the inefficiency of it if solving weren't, y'know, fun.

Anyway, my apologies for posting a partial answer, but it's really time for me to go to bed now. I should get out of the habit of starting puzzles when it's already past a reasonable bedtime...

3, 17 and 37 have been corrected, from either error or research failure.  39's reference has been changed.  36 is a bit of an off-the-wall joke.  (My puzzles are the only ones with patch notes!)

@GarethMcCaughan I think 36 is probably rot13(huhen) with the 'joke' being connected with the noise made throwing up and the seemingly legendary attractiveness of the character. (Plus, there aren't exactly a lot of female 5-letter names beginning with U....)

@Narushiteli Gosh. I always assumed that was a surname (and it is! her first name is apparently Nyota), and I thought everything here was supposed to be a female first/given name. I'm not saying I rejected the possibility on those grounds; it never would have occurred to me in a hundred years.

@GarethMcCaughan 36 is not Trek.  Would it help if I specified jngre alzcu? (Meanwhile, 17 has a straightforward explanation, I swear.)

17 is ro(-of) ba (-rnegu)l

@Exal I have a guess at what you're aiming at for 36 but wouldn't it need to be 6 letters?

@GarethMcCaughan ..................Yes.

OK, I think that's everything done now.
